# casting a java argument from String to LinkedList

Tags: java, casting, linked-list

I have a java program called "run.java" which calls another program called "Main.java".

Main.java takes as an argument a LinkedList.
So i should pass this LinkedList from run.java to Main.java

so, in Main.java, how can I cast the argument from string to LinkedList ?

Comment: this does not make any sense without providing some code.

Comment: You can't cast a String to a LinkedList :) IMO you have misunderstood something, I'd recommend telling us what you want to do (ex: I want to make a program that stores 10 strings in a LinkedList) or posting some example code so we can understand you better.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to transform an array of strings (`String[] args`)  into a linked list, then use this code :

```
LinkedList<String> argsAsLinkedList = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(args));
```

But a method should almost never take a LinkedList as argument. It should take a List. Use interfaces rather than concrete classes for your arguments : it allows your method to work with other kinds of lists.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to tokenize your String, have a look at the StringTokenizer class.